# Dell MD3000, MD1000 and 2950

Tags: dell, sas, dell-powervault

I have a Dell 2950 with MD3000, MD1000 ; Suddenly the I have lost all drives on both of the enclosures and all drives on the MD3000/1000 are blinking, but only ONE Light on each disk, not 2 Lights.

I have tried dell doc and can't seem to find this light status code so far, will be grateful if someone could assist as to what may be the cause or have I lost all data ?

This is a lab environment and the data on it is mainly file shares for our in-house staff.

we can afford to loose data but there are some folders which we would like to recover if possible.

If for example : (a) The SAS Card is dead, can we just replace the sas card and we would get our data back or are we done :-)

`Important Update`

``I have just checked the Raid Logs - it says "Media Scrub Scan Completed" and right after that it says `Event Type 2023 : Virtual Disk Deleted`

No one has deleted the virtual disk, I have tried changing SAS Cards, MD3000 Raid Controllers, SAS cables but MDSM always shows Physical Drives and shows No Disk Groups or Virtual Disks.

Any thoughts ?
Will be grateful

Comment: rihatum, I have a similar issue - were you able to resolve it? What version of firmware were you running on your MD3000?

Comment: Calling Dell support would be a pretty reasonable place to start, I think.

Answer (score 3):

Try to get into MDSM and see what's going on, it can provide some good indication of the system status. If the SAS HBA is busted it's easy to spot - you won't be able to get MDSM connected using in-band connections, and will have to go OOB.

A controller might be gone, and you can just swap them out, or try to start with just one (they them both)

If the MD3000 and MD1000 are not separate, but are in a cascade, you might want to try and just connect to the MD3000 without anything hooked into it.

The key is to try components in an isolated way, and once the culprit is found, fix it.

The more important key is - call Dell support, they are much better at these things than anyone else can be

Comment: Just to update : 2 Blue Lights (One on each enclosure)
One Green Light on Each Hard Disk, as compared to TWO (2) green lights when it is working - Also, when I open MDSM it shows as OPTIMAL, but shows no VDISK or DISK GROUP configured  - Thank you for your prompt responses

Comment: ``incorrect mode parameters modified and saved on physical disk``
Above messages are logged as well - MDSM shows Optimal, shows Physical Drives but shows No RAID GROUPS / DiskGroups / Virtual Disks - Any idea - still waiting Dell to reply and the clock is ticking :-)
Thanks

Comment: Important Update

``I have just checked the Raid Logs - it says "Media Scrub Scan Completed" and right after that it says Event Type 2023 : Virtual Disk Deleted

No one has deleted the virtual disk, I have tried changing SAS Cards, MD3000 Raid Controllers, SAS cables but MDSM always shows Physical Drives and shows No Disk Groups or Virtual Disks.

Any thoughts ? Will be grateful

Comment: looks like raid metadata corruption of some sort. You really need Dell or LSI specialists to look at this

Comment: thanks dyasny, we are still awaiting dell response, I have the raid logs on me - and it shows :

```Event type: 5023  
Event category: Command  
Priority: Informational  
Description: RAID Controller Module return status/function call for requested operation  
Event specific codes: 1/1c/0  
Component type: RAID Controller Module Firmware  
Component location: None  
Logged by: RAID Controller Module in slot 1```  

```Event type: 2203  
Description: Disk group or virtual disk deleted  
Event specific codes: 0/0/0  
Component type: Virtual Disk  
Component location: Virtual Disk 2```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see a status within the Dell Modular Disk Storage Manager on the 2950.  The MDSM software should point you toward a specific hardware issue.  Also, what color are the lights that you do see on the drives and array?

I presume this is a single controller array, connected to a single port SAS card?  If not, have you tried switching SAS ports and EMM ports(after shutting down the attached host, of course)?

FYI...drives disappeared on my MD3000 the other night, after updating my MDSM software.  All was well after rebooting the host system.

Comment: Just to update : 2 Blue Lights (One on each enclosure)
One Green Light on Each Hard Disk, as compared to TWO (2) green lights when it is working - Also, when I open MDSM it shows as OPTIMAL, but shows no VDISK or DISK GROUP configured - Thank you for your prompt responses

Comment: ``incorrect mode parameters modified and saved on physical disk``
Above messages are logged as well - MDSM shows Optimal, shows Physical Drives but shows No RAID GROUPS / DiskGroups / Virtual Disks - Any idea - still waiting Dell to reply and the clock is ticking :-)
Thanks

Comment: Important Update

``I have just checked the Raid Logs - it says "Media Scrub Scan Completed" and right after that it says Event Type 2023 : Virtual Disk Deleted

No one has deleted the virtual disk, I have tried changing SAS Cards, MD3000 Raid Controllers, SAS cables but MDSM always shows Physical Drives and shows No Disk Groups or Virtual Disks.

Any thoughts ? Will be grateful